# Calculating F-Ratio (F-value) for multiple regression in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, anova

In a statistics course for management and economics I am taking we were given a dataset consisting of information about job applicants (age, school and bachelor grades, number of internships performed, time spent abroad, performance during an interview) and an assessment of their job performance after they were hired. We are supposed to analyze which variables predict later job performance using multiple linear regressions. In total we are supposed to fit four models that subsequently add more and more predictors and compare their R^2, F-value, p-value for the F-test, and explain if the model holds explanatory value.

So far I have the following code:

```
#import function for calculating linear regression models with heteroscadacity robust standard errors
url_robust <-"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IsidoreBeautrelet/economictheoryblog/master/robust_summary.R"
eval(parse(text = getURL(url_robust, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)), envir=.GlobalEnv)

#calculate linear models
lm_1 <- lm(performance ~ age + sex, data_A)
summary(lm_1, robust = T)

lm_2 <- lm(performance ~ age + sex + school + bachelor, data_A)
summary(lm_2, robust = T)

lm_3 <- lm(performance ~ age + sex + school + bachelor + abroad + internships, data_A)
summary(lm_3, robust = T)

lm_4 <- lm(performance ~ age + sex + school + bachelor + abroad + internships + interview, data_A)
summary(lm_4, robust = T)
```

Here is my output from the summary core of lm_4:

```
Call:
lm(formula = performance ~ age + sex + school + bachelor + abroad + 
internships + interview, data = data_A)

 Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
    -1.26292 -0.31620 -0.00085  0.29548  1.51859 

 Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
 (Intercept)  2.073422   1.046419   1.981   0.0527 .
 age          0.011915   0.023007   0.518   0.6067  
 sex          0.046603   0.149346   0.312   0.7562  
 school      -0.192044   0.123340  -1.557   0.1254  
 bachelor     0.243797   0.111866   2.179   0.0338 *
 abroad       0.015325   0.009493   1.614   0.1124  
 internships  0.037040   0.041557   0.891   0.3768  
 interview    0.339886   0.216935   1.567   0.1231  
 ---
 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

 Residual standard error: 0.4776 on 53 degrees of freedom
    (5 observations deleted due to missingness)
 Multiple R-squared:  0.3195,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.2297 
 F-statistic:  4.18 on 7 and 53 DF,  p-value: 0.0009912
```

Additionally I have the solutions we are supposed to obtain for each of the parameters from our model as well as the coefficients of model 4 (the most complex model with highest number of predictors).

[image: R^2, F-value, P-value and explanatory significance for each of the four linear models]

[image: non-standardized and standardized coefficients of model 4 including t-value and p-value]

So far the models I fitted seem to be correct since I obtain the same coefficients with the same t and p-values. My issue is that in the F-test on the multiple linear model I obtain the F-statistic instead of the F-value. Based on my research I believe that the different between F-statistic and F-value (also sometimes called F-ratio) is that the F-statistic is the critical F-value (i.e. that value where if the F-value is smaller than it the F-test is no longer statistically significant) and the F-value/F-ratio is the actual test value. Is this correct? In R I would also like to obtain the F-value. Our professor uses gretl to solve his problems instead of R and gretl apparently always gives you the F-value for linear regression models instead of the F-statistic. I have tried many different methods of somehow getting this F-value but I can't get any of them to work. I will post my failed solution approach below. Any suggestions on how I can get the F-value for each of these models would be highly appreciated! Also if anyone could explain how exactly the F-value would in theory be calculated for one of my models (probably lm_1 would be most practical since it has the fewest number of predictors) that would really help me since I think my current issue is that I have misunderstood something about calculating the F-value.

(For simplicities sake I always started with the least complex model and wanted to find a solution for that and then work my way up to the more complex ones).

**Approach 1: perform an anova on my model**

```
anova(lm_1)
```

Console Output:

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: performance
          Df  Sum Sq  Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
age        1  0.1212 0.121247  0.4054 0.5266
sex        1  0.0170 0.016995  0.0568 0.8124
Residuals 63 18.8425 0.299087
```

Here I obtain two different F-values. As far as I understood the anova analysis the first one in the row for age is only testing the effect of age without sex and the second one tests the affect of sex while removing the effects analyzed in the row above? Am still a bit confused about this.

Since F value = variance of the group means (Mean Square Between) / mean of the within group variances (Mean Squared Error), I wanted to manually calculate the F-value form the Anova output but I wasn't exactly sure how to proceed. All solutions I tried did not lead to the F-value I should be obtaining. Could someone explain how I would go about calculating it?

In my research I also often came across the phrase nested models and that this would then give me the F-value which analyses the entire model. Sadly I couldn't figure out what a nested model exactly is and how I would have to input this into R.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: No, F value and F statistics mean the same thing. The only question is whether the test compares the same models and uses the same hypothesis.

Comment: I believe R is return the F statistic, not the critical F.

Comment: @Roland. Then I can't quite explain why the results I get are different to the ones from my professor. The F-test for a multiple regression would have the same hypothesis or? Sadly we didn't discuss F-tests in much detail only how to interpret their significance in the context of linear regression models.

Comment: @Axeman That was my first assumption as well. At some point in my research to find out why the F-statistic I get is different to the one in our results I came across it somewhere that R returns the F-statistic and that this is different to the F-value. I will try and find the source again, maybe it was incorrect though. Any suggestions on where I can find out what R returns exactly?

Comment: This is how R calculates the F-value if there is an intercept and no weights: `f <- fitted(lm.mod); 
mss <- sum((f - mean(f))^2); 
p <- lm.mod$rank; 
resvar <- sum(residuals(lm.mod)^2)/lm.mod$df.residual; 
F <- (mss/(p - 1))/resvar` However, you overload the `summary.lm` function which might change this.